# What happens with community-handled flags

Tags: support, flags

I have flagged a post of a user for asking `canihaztehcodez` questions and having duplicate accounts. However after I flagged the post for mod attention the community (not the user, but the real community as in "us") deleted the question. Hence my flag now has the status of "helpful", but I think those users (the dupe accounts) still need moderator attention.

Will my flag still be on the mods' radar or do I have to flag another post for mods' attention?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When your flag is cleared as "helpful" it gets removed from the moderator dashboard automatically.  Normally you'd have to flag another post for moderator attention, but I looked at your recent flags and found the one you're writing about.

Comment: I suspected it to be removed from the flagged queue. Does this also mean you are looking into it / have looked into it?

Comment: @PeeHaa Yes, I am looking at this now.  Can you tell me why you think these two accounts are the same person?  I don't see any similarity other than generally bad questions.  Was there something specific that you can link me to?

Comment: There was a comment on one of the users accounts stating so. The user said so himself although I cannot find that particular comment anymore. But only looking at the code in the questions should show it's the same user. Might be the case that the question to which the comment was added is deleted now, but you super powerful ubermods should be able to find that comment again right :-)

Comment: @PeeHaa You're right. Looking back a few days, I did finally find two questions that contain the same code.  Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @BilltheLizard - There's also apparently a third account by this user. See my comment in the TL.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a bug, or at the very least a usability or workflow flaw. If a post is flagged "for ♦ moderator attention" it probably shouldn't be cleared until it reaches a ♦ moderator. It should only be cleared if it was flagged for one of the reasons that push the flag to 10k users first.

First, consider that the "other" message:

- Isn't seen by 10k users.
- Will never be seen by ♦ moderators.

If it weren't for PeeHaa paying attention to this flaw and being an experienced user, this issue with the duplicate accounts may not have been handled properly.

Comment: The flags being cleared automatically isn't a flaw in the workflow, the workflow is designed to only consider flags on posts and clearing the flags when the post is deleted makes sense. The "flaw" is that we don't have a way for people to flag user accounts (and I'm not sure we'd want that), and PeeHaa's flag was a hack (it's the common workaround when you absolutely must flag people instead of content).